# how to identify the thread which is causing JVM CPU utilization is reaching to 90 to 100% in Jboss java application?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, cpu-usage, mod-cluster

Our java application(ear) was deployed in J Boss+Linux and We are using mod clusters and have total 8 JV M's or j Boss instances.

We could see that daily one or two of JV M's CPU utilization is reaching to 100% and making application is very slow.

I have tried to get the thread dump by using the j stack and kill Linux commands to identify the causing thread.But unfortunately JV M is not responding if CPU utilization is reaches more than 60% for these commands.

is there any easiest way to identify the thread/method/class name which is causing the issues to increase the CPU utilization?

Could anyone provide the solution asap please?

Answer (score 0):

To get the stack from a hung process use `jstack -F <PID>`, see [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/tooldescr.html#gblfh)

Other solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420501/jstack-target-process-not-responding)

Comment: jstack: Target process not responding Thread                                                             13700: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.jboss.console.plugins.AOPLister$RefreshPoller.run() @bci=41, line=898 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13699: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run() @bci=22, line=1590 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, li

Comment: HI I am getting Thread dump as above if I use the Jstack -F <PID>.How to identify which thread is causing the issue ?

Comment: I could see most of the answers are replacing openJDK with Sun.But we can't change in production. Could you please any best option how to get the thread dump and identify which thread is actually causing the issue?

Comment: I would create a number of thread dumps and compare them, normally you can see a pattern to identify the causing thread. You will see a lot of threads in wait and socket read etc, they are not the problem. The thread that cause this will probably have a longer call stack.

Comment: Could you please advise how to identify which thread is causing issue and how to search in thread dump ?

Comment: Is there any other way to get the thread dump in production application other than jstack since hotspot is not responding most of the times?

Comment: Not what I know about. And about advise I dont have more then I already gave you. Hope you can use them, and hope you find the problem

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote the JVM is not responsive and thus there is no way to get details about executed classes/methods.
Thus the answer to "is there any easiest way" would be "NO". ;-)

But maybe it can help you or anyone else (questions was asked 2.5 years ago) what I would do in this case:

1. Identify the linux thread (I use the small linux tool "threadcpu" for this).
2. Do an strace on the found PID - maybe with longer strings ("-s 1024").

This could give you a hint which class/method is currently executed. If you see e.g. many hundreds SQL queries only used in one single class then this could help you a lot.

"threadcpu" can be downloaded from here: [tuxad.com](http://www.tuxad.com/blog/archives/2018/10/01/threadcpu_-_show_cpu_usage_of_threads/index.html)