# Eclipse Java SOAP calls extremely slow on Linux but fine on PC

Tags: java, linux, windows, performance, soap

I am developing a WS client to pull data from a remote server. I used eclipse to build the objects to access the server via the WSDL file. When I run the code from my PC it runs fine, performance is what I would expect given the Network connection etc that I have.

When I export the JAR and run from my Linux Server,it will run ultimately, each call takes ~2 minutes.

Our network guys did some packet captures, and they saw the POST and ACKs from the initial connection establishment, then 120+ seconds of no activity then a request packet is sent to the server and responses comeback quickly as expected.

It appears there is something blocking the call, but the code is the same between both PC and server.

Has anyone seen similar issues? The Server, which I do not have access to is a windows based server, and the client side is a Linux server.

according to the jstack it appears to be blocked in the socketRead0 for like 120+ seconds

```
     "main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000f2b6000 nid=0x5776 runnable [0x00002ae42ae1d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can run your app with debug mode than simply try to debug it from IDE - [Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

If not - ask operations to make threaddumps - [jstack: Target process not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420501/jstack-target-process-not-responding)
And analyze what is going on during waiting - [How to analyze a java thread dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599608/how-to-analyze-a-java-thread-dump)

Comment: I rand the jstack, it is hanging in the  socketRead0 call. it appears from the jstack as well as what out network engineers are seeing that the connection is blocked until the remote closes the connection even though all the data bas been received.